# problem with VS 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have a program I converted from vs 2003 to vs 2005 . It has worked fine so far  until I changed one of the Dlls.

Funny enough I had just One error . Maximum Number of errrors Exceeded and No other indication of other Error.

Please I have been trying to fix these for like 2 days now.

These Error is actually a compile time error. It show Number of Errors not Warnings. I can't seem to build the web site

Comment: Don't you mean maximum number of warnings?

Comment: You'll have to give more detail. Is this a compile-time or runtime error? Exactly under what circumstances does it occur?

Comment: Did you get this fixed? Usually when you get the "Error 102 Maximum number of errors has been exceeded" message, it is preceded by 102 other error messages. 102 being the magic limit.

Answer (score 0):

The third-party dependency you're linking to is a different version than what the site was coded against. Check the version in your reference list against the actual file version. If the DLL is unmanaged COM it needs to be registered via the regsvr32.exe Windows command, before you can link to it.

It could even be licensing issues for the component, depending if the DLL expects licensing information.

Comment: Thanks . I am actually linking OracleDataAccess.dll from  the ODp.net folder in oracle 11g client

Comment: Migrating from 2003 to 2005, the project more than likely referenced the DLL targeting .Net 1, remove and add the reference again, make sure it's for .Net 2 http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html